# Python - Move files to root directory in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, root, sudo, shutil

I have to move all files from a particular directory to a `root` directory by using Python script. I failed with the following code with `[Errno 13] Permission denied` error.

```
import shutil
import os

source = '../json' 
dest = '/var/www/json'
files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    shutil.move(source+"/"+f, dest)
```

Is it possible to add `sudo` with this code or is there any other method to move files to root folder?
I am working in Ubuntu16.04

Comment: did you try executing your script with sudo ? does the root folder has write permissions for other users ?

Comment: Yes, I think writing `sudo python scirpt_name.py` in the terminal would work.

Comment: Thank you. It works. But is there any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three possible solutions to this:

1. Running python as sudo: `sudo python script.py`. Probably not the nicest way as there are possible security concerns.
2. Change the permissions of the folder so the user running the python script has access to copy/edit files in those folders.
3. Call `cp`/`mv` as a subprocess from python as root. Basically the same as the first option. Can either be done by getting the user to type in root's password which I guess isn't great for you. Or you can use something like `polkit` to avoid using a password.

I would suggest the 2nd option is best and easiest in the long run.

Comment: It works perfectly. The second option was best for me

Answer (score 1):

you could add your user to the folder permissions and give the user write access to that folder.
use chown or chmod to adjust permissions on the destination folder